# Proof verification - Discarding a subcase of odd perfect numbers

Tags: solution-verification, perfect-numbers

Thinking about the problem of the existence of odd perfect numbers, I elaborated the following ideas. I post them here for you to check if they are correct, or point out the errors.

We define the sum of divisors function $\sigma\left(n\right)$ as the sum of all the proper divisors of some positive integer $n$. It is not difficult to show that $\sigma\left(n\right)$ has the following properties:

• For some prime number $p$, noting that the sum of divisors function $\sigma\left(p^{\alpha}\right)$ is a geometric progression; we have that $$\sigma\left(p^{\alpha}\right)=1+p+p^{2}+...+p^{\alpha}=\frac{p^{\alpha+1}-1}{p-1}$$

• The sum of divisors function is multiplicative: if two positive integers $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $$\sigma\left(mn\right)=\sigma\left(m\right)\sigma\left(n\right)$$

We define a perfect number $P$ as some positive integer such that $\sigma\left(P\right)=2P$.

Euler's Odd perfect number theorem states that any odd perfect number $P$ must be of the form $P=m^{2}q^{\alpha}$, with $q$ prime, $\alpha\geq1$ and $\gcd\left(m^{2},q\right)=1$.

If $P=m^{2}q^{\alpha}$ and $P$ is some perfect number, then

$$\sigma\left(m^{2}q^{\alpha}\right)=2m^{2}q^{\alpha}$$

As by Euler's odd perfect number theorem we have that $\gcd\left(m^{2},q\right)=1$, then

$$\sigma\left(m^{2}q^{\alpha}\right)=\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)\sigma\left(q^{\alpha}\right)$$

And substituting,

$$2m^{2}q^{\alpha}=\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)\sigma\left(q^{\alpha}\right)$$

As $\sigma\left(q^{\alpha}\right)=\frac{q^{\alpha+1}-1}{q-1}$, substituting we have that

$$2m^{2}q^{\alpha}=\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)\left(\frac{q^{\alpha+1}-1}{q-1}\right) (1)$$

Noting that $\gcd\left(q^{\alpha},\left(\frac{q^{\alpha+1}-1}{q-1}\right)\right)=1$, it follows that $q^{\alpha}$ must divide $\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)$.

Other hand, it is easy to prove that for any integer $n$, $n^k<\frac{n^{k+1}-1}{n-1}<2n^k$. Therefore, $q^{\alpha}<\left(\frac{q^{\alpha+1}-1}{q-1}\right)<2q^{\alpha}$, and for $(1)$ to hold, necessarily $m^2<\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)<2m^2$.

Now, we have two possible cases:

**Case (a): $q^{\alpha}>m^2$**

In this case, we have that $2q^{\alpha}>2m^2>\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)$; therefore, as we have that
$q^{\alpha}$ must divide $\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)$, we get that necessarily $q^{\alpha}=\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)$.

Substituting, we have that
$$q^{\alpha}\left(\frac{q^{\alpha+1}-1}{q-1}\right)=2m^{2}q^{\alpha}$$
$$\frac{q^{\alpha+1}-1}{q-1}=2m^{2}$$

It can be proved (see, for instance, [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285507/a-modification-of-the-ljunggren-nagell-equation)) that the equation $\frac{q^{\alpha+1}-1}{q-1}=2m^{2}$ has solution only for $\alpha+1 \leq 2$. Thus, in this case we get that necessarily $\alpha = 1$, and some odd perfect number $P$ such that $q^{\alpha}>m^2$ can exist only if $P=qm^2$.

However, $\sigma\left(q\right)\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)=(1+q)\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)$. As we have that $m^2<\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)<2m^2$, then $P=qm^2$ is an abundant number, and can not be perfect.

**Case (b): $q^{\alpha}<m^2$**

In this case, $\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)=q^{\alpha}*s$, where $s$ is some odd integer greater than $1$. Substituting, we have that
$$q^{\alpha}s\left(\frac{q^{\alpha+1}-1}{q-1}\right)=2m^{2}q^{\alpha}$$
$$s\left(\frac{q^{\alpha+1}-1}{q-1}\right)=2m^{2}$$
$$\frac{q^{\alpha+1}-1}{q-1}=\frac{2m^{2}}{s}$$

As $\frac{q^{\alpha+1}-1}{q-1}$ is some integer, and $s$ is odd, it follows that $s$ divides $m^2$, and subsequently $s$ is some divisor of $P$. As $\gcd(q^{\alpha},m^2)=1$, it follows that $\gcd(q,s)=1$.

Before dealing further with case (b), I would be grateful if someone could confirm that I can discard case (a) based on the proof exposed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have basically rediscovered my results in [The Abundancy Index of Divisors of Odd Perfect Numbers (Theorem 5, page 3)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), so this is not new.

Comment: In case (a) you could also argue that $\alpha=1$ implies $\sigma\left(m^{2}\right)=q$ is a prime, but by multiplicativity of $\sigma$ it means $m^2$ is a prime power (which is a direct contradiction with known result that potential odd perfect numbers must has certain number of distinct prime factors).

Comment: @Sil good argument, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris thanks for sharing the link!

Answer (score 1):

**Comment converted into an answer, so that this question does not remain in the unanswered queue**

You have basically rediscovered my results in [The Abundancy Index of Divisors of Odd Perfect Numbers (Theorem 5, page 3)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), so this is not new.